# Double not storing number in C (is the number too small)

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

This is my issue, i need to calculate how many clock cycles are in a ms and us for my pll waits on a TM4C123. However the values are coming out as zero on my double making my other values incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float ms_cycled;
    float us_cycled;
    int ms_cycle;
    int us_cycle;
    unsigned long MHz = 50;
    double TPC = 1/(MHz*10000000); //calculate time per clock cycle

    //calculate cycles for ms
    ms_cycled = 0.001/TPC;
    ms_cycle = ms_cycled;
    //calculate cycles for us
    us_cycled = 0.000001/TPC;
    us_cycle = us_cycled;
    printf("TPC = %.16f \n", TPC);
    printf("ms_cycled = %f \n", ms_cycled);
    printf("us_cycled = %f \n", us_cycled);
    printf("ms_cycle = %i \n", ms_cycle);
    printf("us_cycle = %i \n", us_cycle);
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs I get are:

```
TPC = 0.0000000000000000                                                                                                                             
ms_cycled = inf                                                                                                                                      
us_cycled = inf                                                                                                                                      
ms_cycle = -2147483648                                                                                                                               
us_cycle = -2147483648
```

Comment: That is the most inefficient way to calculate clocks per ms I have ever seen. If you have `MHz`, you have clocks per second. And clocks per ms is simple a factor 1/1000 of it. Same goes for clocks per µs which is again a factor of 1/1000. `ms_cycle = MHZ * 1000; us_cycle = MHz`. Your value for `TPC` is off by factor 10 as you multiply MHz with 10^7 instead of 10^6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double TPC = 1/(MHz*10000000);
```

Note that you're using **integer arithmetics**. So you get `1/(50*10000000)` = `1/500000000` = `0` (of type `unsigned long`). Casting zero from `unsigned long` to `double` only gives you `0.0`, not the correct result.

Changing one of the operands to floating point arithmetics should solve the problem:

```
double TPC = 1.0/(MHz*10000000.0)
              ^^              ^^
```

You can alternatively change this for the same result:

```
double MHz = 50.0;
               ^^
```

Comment: Note that if `MHz` is changed to `double`, it is no longer crucial that the other numbers be converted to floating point as the fact that `MHz` is `double` ensures that the calculation is done in `double` arithmetic.

Comment: The question isn't whether you know it; it's whether the OP knows it.  Type consistency isn't bad, but it isn't always necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Got it. I re-worded my answer now.

Comment: Hello, please, can you also tell what's the difference between 1.0 and 1.0f please? I know that you can write those two ways but I don't know the difference

Comment: @Cjdcoy `1.0` is of type **double**, while `1.0f` is of type **float**.

Comment: fantastic, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The expression `1/(MHz*10000000)` has type `unsigned long` and value 0. Storing the result in a `double` does not make the result any less zero. Use `1.0/(MHz*10000000)` instead.